# Ruby on Rails - exclude results by adding a param to a URL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need to add a parameter to this url:
https://my.app/users.json?active=true&p=1

to be like this:
https://my.app/users.json?active=true&p=1&exclude=[has_a_car=true]

The syntax `exclude=[has_a_car=true]` is just an example to illustrate what I need: to exclude users with the attribute *has_a_car* with value = *true*.

This is being processed by the `UsersController#index` function in server side.

Is there a best practice to accomplish this? Maybe a built in feature in rails?

Comment: What have you built so far? How did you implement the filters that are already working?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following parameters instead:

```
?active=true&p=1&exclude[has_a_car]=true
```

Rails knows this parameter syntax and converts it to:

```
{ "active" => "true", "p" => "1", "exclude" => { "has_a_car" => "true" } }
```